# An error is encountered as "Access is denied" when trying to change MySQL root password

Tags: mysql, access-denied, reset-password

I tried to change the root password of MySQL server by following [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html).

But I get an error as **Access is denied** when I'm at Step **6**. Refer the below attachment as well.

[image]

Can someone tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: have you tried running as admin

Comment: @L_Church Yes. I tried it. Then I got following error. "'C:\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 0):

try to follow given url steps, I hope it will work

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: I'm following this one. While following I got this error

Comment: I tried it now. As it says, server should be started after changes are done. But nothing happen after the command. Just blinking the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

In step 6 of documentation they tell you how to start your database then they put alternative syntax if your my.ini file is located elsewhere

Here your first command mysqld --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt worked properly so the file C:\mysql-init.txt is in use so you can't start database using same file mysql-init.txt which is in use so there is a message "Access is denied"

So as your database is started properly, you can go forward to step 7